# Extending JUnit4

Tags: junit4

I would like to run a series of integration tests against a system. I would like to ditch the boilerplate @Before and @After code that just involves getting and releasing a session. What is the best way to achieve this? The session should also be exposed to the test methods via getSession() method as well. This was very straightforward in JUnit3 - but it's not so obvious to me in JUnit4.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an (abstract) parent class which contains your "boilerplate" code and make your concrete test classes extend that parent class (this solution seems very obvious for me but maybe I did not understand your use case correct - what do you mean by "very straightforward in JUnit3"?).

Comment: Sorry I should've clearer. I meant to say that in JUnit3 I can extend TestCase with an abstract class, overriding setUp/tearDown to handle session management. In JUnit4 however there are no setUp/tearDown methods to override. Do annotations support inheritance? e.g. could I create an abstract class, annotate a setUp method with @Before and have this setup routine fire automatically on a concrete implementation of this class?

Comment: @ukdavo Yes - have a look at the [@Before JavaDoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html)